# I hav a java ee application and i want to assign from two drop downs

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

I hava an assignment in which to create a java ee application with the ability to assign a tutor to an office, i have two entity classes one called Tutors.java and the other Offices.java. The drop downs populate but when i want to assign the two values and hit the submit button it throws a null pointer at the server.allocateTutorOffice in the java bean. I realise the problem is with the server class but I'm unsure how to change it to solve the problem.

```
 TutorBean.java
    public void allocateTutorOffice(){
         server.allocateTutorOffice(tutor.getOfficeId(), tutor.getId());
         tutor = new Tutors();
        }

    TutorServer.java
       @Override
        public void allocateTutorOffice(Offices officeId, int Id) {

            Tutors t = manager.find(Tutors.class, Id);
            //Offices o = manager.find(Offices.class, officeId);
            e.setOfficeId(officeId);
            manager.merge(t);

        }




Staff maintence.jsp
     <c:choose>
     <c:when test="${not empty param.allocate}">
                  <fmt:parseNumber var="e" type="number" value="${param.e.id}" />
                  <fmt:parseNumber var="o" type="number" value="${param.o.id}" />
                  <c:set var="e" scope="request" value="${tutor.tutor}"/>
                  <c:set var="o" scope="request" value="${office.office}"/>
                  <jsp:setProperty name="e" property="officeId"/>
                  <% employee.allocateTutorOffice();%>

            </c:when>
 </c:choose>



  <h2> Allocate Office</h2>
     <jsp:useBean id="office" class="cmm502.cw.web.OfficesBean" scope="session"/>
        <form method="post" action="StaffMaintence.jsp">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Employee Id:

                        <select>
                             <c:forEach var="e" items="${tutor.tutors}">
                            <option value="${t.id}">${t.id}</option>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </select>
                </td>

                      <td>Office Id:
                        <select>
                            <c:forEach var="o" items="${office.offices}">
                            <option value="${o.id}">${o.id}</option>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </select>

              <td>
                  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${e.id}"/>
                  <input type="submit" name="allocate" value="allocate"/></td>
                 </tr>
                 </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: i have changed the allocate method in the server to    public void allocateEmployeeOffice(int officeId, int id) {
       
        Offices o = manager.find(Offices.class, officeId);
        Employees e = manager.find(Employees.class, id);
        e.setOfficeId(o);
        manager.merge(e);
        
    }

Answer (score 0):

I think the object "server" is of type TutorServer. Please try to instantiate that object by doing server = new TutorServer() and then call the method allocateTutorOffice(). But i feel that you are invoking a business functionality from a bean class which is not a good design.